# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have written this code:

```
string _response = null;
string _auth = "Basic";
Uri _uri = new Uri("http://my.domain.local/my-page.aspx");
HttpWebRequest _req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.olr.com/Service.svc");
CredentialCache _cc = new CredentialCache();
HttpWebResponse _res = default(HttpWebResponse);
StreamReader _sr = default(StreamReader);

_cc.Add(_uri, _auth, new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "ttp://api.olr.com/Service.svc"));
_req.PreAuthenticate = true;
_req.Credentials = _cc.GetCredential(_uri, _auth);
var response = _req.GetResponse();

System.IO.StreamReader sr =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(_res.GetResponseStream());

//_sr = new StreamReader(_res.GetResponseStream);
_response = _sr.ReadToEnd();
_sr.Close();
```

but getting:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

at

```
var response = _req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Do you control the server, or does it belong to someone else? If the former, then the first place to look is in the logs on the server to find out why you get a 401 status returned. Well of course, I'm assuming that you already tested the same credentials with a browser and got the same result.

Comment: @DominicCronin It is third party service

Comment: Have your tried adding User agent header, some servers does not allow clients without a proper useragent

Comment: possible duplicate of [401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202882/401-unauthorized-access-is-denied-due-to-invalid-credentials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed 'h' in "http://api.olr.com/Service.svc"

```
 _cc.Add(_uri, _auth, new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "ttp://api.olr.com/Service.svc"));
```

and also set WebProxy

```
System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://api.olr.com", true);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("platinum", "01CFE4BF-11BA", "http://api.olr.com/Service.svc");
_req.Proxy = proxy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your NetworkCredential is constructed properly. According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytcd70k.aspx), the third property is the domain, but you are passing the full URL. You need to find out from the third party what the correct domain is.

In the mean time, you could try leaving that property out to see if the login will succeed.