# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am trying to consume a third party service like this:

```
 var context = new DataSource(new Uri("http://api.olr.com/Service.svc"));

 context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "http://api.olr.com/Service.svc");


 var agents = from a in context.Agents
                     select a;

 tbResponse.Text = agents.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

but getting reponse:

```
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
 <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
 <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
```

I tried to access the service using browser and it is working.

third parameter to following line is domain. what to put in domain ? the Service url as i did ?

```
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "http://api.olr.com/Service.svc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetworkCredential constructor is expecting username, password and domain but you are passing in the full Url instead of the domain.

I would change that line to:

```
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "olr.com");
```

**UPDATE - Solution that worked:**

```
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Was the solution.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Then try instantiating NetworkCredential only with username and password (there's a constructor that only takes username and password) and see if that works. You claim what you can access this url using a browser; therefore, the same way you enter your credentials in the browser should work in your program.

Comment: Icarus, can you update your answer to reflect the working solution?  :)

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, Terry, answer updated to reflect the working code.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the domain associated with the passed credentials. The serviced that you have mentioned is hosted in some machine, I guess you should pass the domain name of that machine.

Comment: Try using "api.olr.com". I tried the URL in my browser and I was prompted to enter credentials for the server api.olr.com:80. Here 80 is the port.